# How to refresh firebase DB Auth token before it expires?

Tags: python, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, access-token

I am using python to write to my firebase DB. I have thousands of dataset that will take hours to complete. My program has repeatedly being stopped with this error

> > "Auth token is expired"

I searched for solution but could not find any, i later found that one can check for the time left before it expire and refresh the token so that there would not be any interruption in the data transfer. 
How can I refresh the token before it expires?

Answer (score 1):

I am using django with firebase and the pyrebase module. I too encountered a similar issue. I found the solution on github :-> https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/issues/244 
Right after this code->

```
config = {
    'apiKey': "your-api-key",
    'authDomain': "your-auth-domain",
    'databaseURL': "your-db-url",
    'projectId': "your-project-id",
    'storageBucket': "your-storage-bucket",
    'messagingSenderId': "your-messaging-sender-id",
}
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
auth = firebase.auth()
user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password("email@sthn.com", "strong-password")
```

Add this

```
# A user's idToken expires after 1 hour, so be sure to use the user's refreshToken to avoid stale tokens.
user = auth.refresh(user['refreshToken'])
# now we have a fresh token
user['idToken']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh the token when it's about to expire using the google oauth2  lib like this:

```
import httplib2
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("service-account.json", "{scope}")
print(credentials.get_access_token())
credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
print(credentials.get_access_token())
```